# Centering subsections in amsart

Tags: sectioning, amsart

I am writing some kind of notes using amsart. I want to write a subsection (or even a subsubsection) using small caps and centre it. How can I put it in the center?

Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{\bfseries}{\scshape}{}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Comment: amsart subsections are run-in to the following paragraph, you presumably want to make them display headings, as well as center?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can just copy the definition, change from run-in to display, and add `\centering` and `\scshape`

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}
% make this >0 for display heading
{.5\baselineskip}%
% add centering
  {\normalfont\centering\scshape}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\subsection{Hello World}
One two three.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Where should we add the command textsc?

Comment: @Chris I updated the image it's more natural to use the non-argument form `\scshape` so I switched the code to use that as well.

Comment: Splendid, many thanks.